# Can i use both dilated convolution and maxpooling layer both at the same time?

Tags: conv-neural-network, max-pooling, dilation

In my DCNN architecture, where I am using a dilation factor of '2' in each convolution layer and the Maxpooling Layer.I am using both in concatenation. Though it is improving my accuracy, but I am thinking is it right to do so?
As in  dilation we are increasing the receptive field while in Maxpooling we are doing opposite right?
Plz guide